# NoSuchMethodError on inherited method

Tags: java

I'm trying to run a package that has dependencies on several hundred packages and I keep getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.company.jacksonion.JoiObjectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize$Inclusion;)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper;
        at com.company.raft.utils.IonUtil.createJacksonIonMapper(IonUtil.java:33)
        at com.company.raft.utils.IonUtil.<clinit>(IonUtil.java:40)
        at com.company.raft.i18n.MarketplaceManager.loadFromFile(MarketplaceManager.java:96)
        at com.company.raft.i18n.MarketplaceManager.loadAllConfigs(MarketplaceManager.java:55)
        at com.company.raft.env.EnvManager.<init>(EnvManager.java:118)
        at com.company.raft.env.EnvManager.instance(EnvManager.java:147)
    at com.company.raft.bases.AbstractTestBase.<init>(AbstractTestBase.java:49)
    at com.company.product.peekaboo.test.bases.PeekabooTestBase.<init>(PeekabooTestBase.java:38)
        at com.company.product.engine.peekaboo.tests.GetAddressOfDeviceTests.<init>(GetAddressOfDeviceTests.java:21)
```

I didn't write the above packages but according to the internal codebase they are the latest stable changes and when I look at the actual file `com.company.raft.utils.IonUtil.createJacksonIonMapper`:

```
    JoiObjectMapper mapper = new JoiObjectMapper();
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);
```

the method `setSerializationInclusion` is in `JoiObjectMapper`'s superclass' superclass. So why is it unable to find the method?

Comment: More than likely JAR versioning issues; ensure you have the proper versions to correspond to each other

Comment: Looks like a dependency version issue. How are you bringing in dependencies? Maven perhaps?

Comment: Probably because you have several versions of this class in the runtime classpath.

Comment: @JBNizet I checked that but there's only version of the com.company.raft package and the com.company.jacksonion package in my dependency set